# How to select rows with given set of values

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following table:

Table USERS_GROUPS

```
USER_ID | GROUP_ID
100         1
101         1
101         2
102         1
102         2
102         3
103         1
103         2
103         3
```

I need to select only those users who has all groups (1, 2 and 3) i.e.

Query result:

```
USER_ID
102
103
```

How to compose such sql query?

Comment: No evidence you've tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most flexible way to structure such a query is using `group by` and `having`.  If you want those three specific groups:

```
select ug.user_id
from users_groups ug
group by ug.user_id
having sum(case when group_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when group_id = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when group_id = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 ;
```

If you want users that are in all groups in the table:

```
select ug.user_id
from users_groups ug
group by ug.user_id
having count(distinct ug.group_id) = (select count(distinct group_id) from user_groups);
```

Comment: Your second solution is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the result.  The `WHERE` clause will include the list of the `group_ids` that you want.  You will apply the `GROUP BY` clause to your `user_id` column and finally you will use the `HAVING` clause to get a count of the distinct `group_ids` - this count should match the number of ids that you have in the `WHERE`:

```
select user_id
from USERS_GROUPS
where group_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by user_id
having count(distinct group_id) = 3;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6e6d7/1)

Answer (score 0):

A solution without using `distinct` such as for Microsoft Access SQL:

```
SELECT USER_ID
FROM (SELECT user_id, group_id
      FROM USERS_GROUPS
      WHERE group_id IN (1,2,3)
      GROUP BY user_id, group_id
      ) T
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id) = 3
```

A demo in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f16353/5)