# Something like GROUP BY HAVING ALL IN

Tags: sql

I want to select a ProductConfig that has exactly the given variants. As it is a many-to-many relationship I have an association table. With the association table I have been trying to use it with the `GROUP BY` so I can work on the other column.

The problem I am having is that I need an exactly equal operator to a set of values inside the `HAVING`. Something like `HAVING variant_id = (1, 2, 3, 99)`.

For now I have the following query with some problems

```sql
SELECT productconfig_id
FROM association_productconfig_elementvariant
GROUP BY productconfig_id
HAVING variant_id IN (1, 2, 3, 99);
```

This will match if `productconfig_id` has `variant_id` equal to ANY subset of `{1, 2 3, 99}` like `{1, 2}` or `{1, 3}` but I only want it to match with the exact set `{1, 2, 3, 99}`.

I have another problem the other way around. If `productconfig_id` has `variant_id` equal to `{1, 2, 50}` it will also match because the first to is in the values even though the last is not.

Basically I want to compare equality over a column and a set of values. This second problem will solve if you had something like `HAVING ALL IN`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows with given set of values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21117331/how-to-select-rows-with-given-set-of-values)

Comment: It partially solves it because that will match if it has more than the variants I want but I don't want more or less. It is related tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more on-target with what you need. Here, I am doing both a COUNT(*) and a sum() based on the matching variant_id in question.  This is making sure that whatever records DO qualify the variant get to the 4 count, but ALSO the count(*) of every variant per configuration.

So, if one product had variants of (1, 2, 3, 5, 12, 99, 102, 150) would have a count(*) = 8, but the specific match = 4 based on those in question.

Now, if you can ignore the overall count of 8, just remove that AND portion from below, but at least you know the primary 4 in consideration are accounted for.

```
SELECT 
      productconfig_id
   FROM 
      association_productconfig_elementvariant
   GROUP BY 
      productconfig_id
   HAVING 
      sum( case when variant_id in ( 1, 2, 3, 99 )
                then 1 else 0 end ) = 4
      AND count(*) = 4
```

Comment: I don't think I can ignore the overall count because without that condition it will be the subset case. With that 2 conditions I think this is the correct answer. Let me check. Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer. The first condition asserts that all the values are present in the set and the second condition asserts that no more unknown items are present. Thanks!

Comment: You could eliminate `count(*) = 4` by replacing 0 with an off-the-scale value in the sum. I must admit that does make it obfuscated: `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN variant_id IN (1, 2, 3, 99) THEN 1 ELSE 5 END) = 4`

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
Select productconfig_id
From (
SELECT productconfig_id, count(1) as _count
FROM association_productconfig_elementvariant
GROUP BY productconfig_id
HAVING variant_id IN (1, 2, 3, 99)
) as s where _count = 4;
```

Basicly the only productconfig with count = 4 will be the one you are looking for.

Comment: I thought of that but imagine the case where 2 productconfig has {1, 2, 3, 50} and {1, 2, 3, 51}, that query will still match because of the length even if one id is different. I think you can simplify the query by adding `AND count(variant_id) = 4` in the `HAVING` statement that I have

Comment: I'm pretty sure `HAVING` should be `WHERE` (and above the `GROUP BY` clause to make the syntax valid again). Then it might work, assuming there's a unique constraint on (productconfig_id, variant_id).